# array_push from array to another array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

```
$adatok = DB::select('SELECT * FROM ingatlan');

foreach ($adatok as $adat) {
  array_push($adatok, Storage::files($adat->id));
}
return $adatok;
```

Result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLn4H.png]

I would like to assign them to existing data.
Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try as below.

```
$adatok = DB::select('SELECT * FROM ingatlan');

$return = array();
foreach ($adatok as $adat) {
   $adat->image = Storage::files($adat->id);
   $return[] = $adat;
}
return $return;
```

as you're using `array_push();` it is inserting the value of `Storage::files($adat->id)` after the `$adatok` object which you're getting in select query.

What solution does is all records fetched from the table. for each collection, I've added an image element with value and store in an array. Finally, you'll have an array with images.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `&`to modify the actual objects:

```
foreach ($adatok as &$adat) {
   $adat->image = Storage::files($adat->id);    
}
return $adatok;
```